# create a directory in the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, filesystems, nsfilemanager

What's wrong with that?

```
#define AUDIO_NOTES_FOLDER [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/myApp/Pictures"]

NSFileManager *NSFm= [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
BOOL isDir=YES;

if(![NSFm fileExistsAtPath:FILEPATH isDirectory:&isDir])
    if(![NSFm createDirectoryAtPath:FILEPATH attributes:nil])
        NSLog(@"Error: Create folder failed");
```

Comment: FILEPATH would be undefined. Perhaps you meant AUDIO_NOTES_FOLDER?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The FILEPATH token is undefined - you `#define AUDIO_NOTES_FOLDER` at the beginning of your file, then use `FILEPATH` instead in your code.

Also note that NSHomeDirectory() isn't necessarily the recommended way of finding the Documents directory anymore - instead you probably want:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 13):

`createDirectoryAtPath:attributes:` is deprecated, instead you should use:

```
    NSString *dirToCreate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/newDirectory",[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL isDir;
    if(![fm fileExistsAtPath:dirToCreate isDirectory:&isDir])
        if(![fm createDirectoryAtPath:dirToCreate withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error])
            NSLog(@"Error: Create folder failed");
```